# How do I configure blast+ to access databases on an external hard drive?

Tags: cmd, environment-variables, bioinformatics, blast, ncbi

I installed the [blast+ program](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PAGE_TYPE=BlastDocs&DOC_TYPE=Download) on my computer to use BLAST locally. I also downloaded the complete nr database to my external hard drive. To access it I created an environment variable called BLASTDB with the path to my external hard drive, as was explained in the official [user manual](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK279690/).

When I try to update the nr database with the command prompt:

`update_blastdb.pl --decompress nr`

it downloads it to the current working directory.